# How to split puppet files

Tags: puppet, devops

Just wondering if I have the following puppet file and I would like to split them into separate files. Do I have to create module? Can't I just include them?

```
node default {
  include mysql
}


class mysql {

  # Make sure MySQL is ...
  notify {"Mysql":}

  # installed
  package { 'mysql':
  require => Exec['apt-update'], # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
  }

  # and running
  service { 'mysql':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
  }
}

...
```

I just want to take out mysql class to be on separate file. How to do this simple thing? Btw I'm using masterless puppet

**Edit**

Big big apologies, the truth is I was only using puppet without vagrant. But since I'm not a devops expert, when there was a revision on my question to include vagrant I just accepted it. Sorry for the confusion and let me revise my question

Can I do the separation WITHOUT vagrant? If I have to so be it.

Thanks

Comment: You've tagged [vagrant], but it's unclear how your question is related to Vagrant.

Comment: In it's simplest form, creating a module just means putting the file containing your `mysql` class in an appropriate directory.  That's what you should do if you want to split your manifest into two.

Comment: My apologies, I have my question clearer. That's my bad. Unfortunately thou, even if I put the files in appropriate directory, mine was not detected, probably because the inclusion path was not set properly

Comment: There is a "module path", which I guess is what you mean.  You can set your own in Puppet's configuration, you can specify it on the command line, or you can use the default (which depends on the version of Puppet).  @FrédéricHenri's answer demonstrates how to place the file (`init.pp`), given `./puppet/modules` being a directory in the module path.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, that default path and `module path` variable really helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move your `mysql` class into its own module

you'll end up with something like this

```
.
├── Vagrantfile
├── puppet
|   ├── manifests
|         ├──── base.pp
|   └── modules
|         └── mysql
|               └── manifests
|                     └──── init.pp
```

Vagrantfile would be like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    <make all your configuration here>
    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
      puppet.manifest_file = "base.pp"
      puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    end
  end

end
```

the base.pp file will only contain

```
node default {
  include mysql
}
```

and your mysql/init.pp file will contain the mysql class itself

```
class mysql {

  # Make sure MySQL is ...
  notify {"Mysql":}

  # installed
  package { 'mysql':
  require => Exec['apt-update'], # require 'apt-update' before installing
  ensure => installed,
  }

  # and running
  service { 'mysql':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
  }
}
```

It can be a good idea for module exercise in puppet, but honestly you're more likely to use an existing module and not reinvent the wheel: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/mysql/2.2.3 will be a good module to use

Comment: @JohnBollinger indeed but it was tagged vagrant so I assumed the OP was using puppet from vagrant - true the same can be done without vagrant and the split will be the same

Comment: From this answer, now I know what OP asked for. The expression in question is too hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri I appreciated your answer (+1) and I have updated my question to clear up some confusion. How can I do like you said without vagrant? How to setup the path without vagrant

Comment: Just to close this, without vagrant those file structure can be put on `/etc/puppet` which is the default folder in ubuntu. Should be quite similar to other linux distro